# Error comes after updating PHP version in IIS PHP manager

Tags: php, mysql, database, iis, drupal

The website is not responding after I change the PHP version from v7.4.24 to v7.4.33 in IIS PHP manager.

The error is as follows:

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Undefined class constant 'MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY' in E:\inetpub\wwwroot\intranet\includes\database\mysql\database.inc:56
Stack trace:
#0 E:\inetpub\wwwroot\intranet\includes\database\database.inc(1745): DatabaseConnection_mysql->__construct()
#1 E:\inetpub\wwwroot\intranet\includes\database\database.inc(1535): Database::openConnection()
#2 E:\inetpub\wwwroot\intranet\includes\database\database.inc(2626): Database::getConnection()
#3 E:\inetpub\wwwroot\intranet\includes\cache.inc(359): db_escape_table()
#4 E:\inetpub\wwwroot\intranet\includes\cache.inc(340): DrupalDatabaseCache->getMultiple()
#5 E:\inetpub\wwwroot\intranet\includes\cache.inc(57): DrupalDatabaseCache->get()
#6 E:\inetpub\wwwroot\intranet\includes\module.inc(762): cache_get()
#7 E:\inetpub\wwwroot\intranet\includes\module.inc(962): module_implements()
#8 E:\inetpub\wwwroot\intranet\modules\system\system.module(2519): module_invoke_all()
#9 E:\inetpub\wwwroot\intranet\includes\theme.inc(798): _system_rebuild_theme_data()
#1 in E:\inetpub\wwwroot\intranet\includes\database\mysql\database.inc on line 56

I tried adding PDO extension_dir="path" in PHP.ini file as there was no path assigned to the directory earlier. But the results were same.

Comment: It tries to access a class constant named `MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY`, but apparently that has not been defined anywhere. That's all we can say, based on seeing only the error message, and no code.

Comment: check your php.ini configuration file. Look for lines and make sure they are not commented

extension=pdo_mysql
other this is to update the drupal

Comment: @HasanRaza. Thanks you very much mate. Your answer helped me to solve this. :) The website started working again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. check your php.ini configuration file.
2. Look for lines and make sure they are not commented extension=pdo_mysql
3. other this is to update the drupal